# Show that $\det(A-I_3)^2+ \det(A-2I_3)^2 +\cdots+\det(A-2nI_3)^2\geqslant\frac{\det A^2}{\binom{2n}{4n}-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> For any real matrix $A$ of dimension $3$ and for any $n \geqslant 2$, show that$$\det(A-I_3)^2+ \det(A-2I_3)^2 +\cdots+\det(A-2nI_3)^2\geqslant\frac{\det A^2}{\binom{4n}{2n}-1}.$$

I know that $\det(A-xI_3)$ is equal to zero polynomial from Cayley-Hamilton, but I do not know what I should use to deal with the binomial and to solve it. Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please see "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for advice on how to compose the best posts here

Comment: I've [edit]ed this post to remove the [display style in the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/why-no-use-displaystyle-in-titles).

Comment: I'm confused by the binomial term as well.  For $n\gt 0$, $2n$ is less than $4n$, so by convention we'd have $\binom{2n}{4n}=0$.  Is there some typo here?

Comment: Setting the binomial term to zero makes the inequality true, in the trivial sense that a sum of nonnegative terms is greater than or equal to a nonpositive term.  It seems better to put zero there, if that is the intent.

Comment: I have made the required changes.